# Unambiguous Opposite of "The Subtitle of a Film"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

A word to refer to the "The Far Side of the World" part in the film title [*Master and Commander: The Far Side of the World*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0311113/) (MC:FSW) might be [*subtitle*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subtitle). By [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/42740/39720), the "Master and Commander" part is called *title*. But so is the full title MC:FSW.

I tried negating the prefix with [*supertitle*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/supertitle) and *surtitle*, which are opposites of another meaning of *subtitle*. I also considered location: I'm trying to find a word to describe the **first** part of a title, so I looked for *pretitle*. The uses I found meant "coming in a film before or during its opening credits."

Is there another word that means precisely "title but not subtitle"?

Comment: I'd call it the *series title*, or maybe the *main title* (depending on whether there are other related movies called *Master and Commander: [some other text]*).

Comment: It's the *title*. And it has to be for there to be a *sub-title*.

Comment: BTW what's wrong with *unambiguous*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the ***title***. And it has to be for there to be a *sub-title*.  :)

It's not necessary to say "title but not subtitle" -- the full version should properly be called the *full title (including subtitle)*.

Comment: +1, your explanation of how *sub-title* comes from *title* makes a lot of sense to me. Ideally if a work were named "A: B" I would like one word meaning "A", another "B", and one different from either of those meaning "A: B". But if you have an unambiguous single word meaning *full title (including subtitle)*, I will accept this answer.